# Error When Installing NuGet Packages

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, nuget

When I try to install EF with NuGet in Visual Studio 2013 Pro, I get this error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework.Commands (≥ 7.0.0-beta4)'.
'EntityFramework.Commands' already has a dependency defined for 'EntityFramework.Relational'.
```

When I try to install EntityFramework.Core I get this erro:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ix-Async (≥ 1.2.3)'.
'EntityFramework.Core' already has a dependency defined for 'Ix-Async'.
```

What could possibly be the problem, I've seen others with the issue, they suggested installing an upgraded NuGet, which I did.  The problem persists.  No other solutions have worked.

Any one have any ideas how I can fix this?  It's a VSTO addin for Outlook 2013.

Thanks

EDIT:
After restarting VS2013 after updating NuGet I tried to install EF again, got a new error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework.Commands (≥ 7.0.0-beta4)'.
Installing 'EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4'.
Executing script file 'C:\Users\shenk\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Archiver\packages\EntityFramework.Commands.7.0.0-beta4\tools\init.ps1'.
Installing 'EntityFramework 7.0.0-beta4'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 7.0.0-beta4'.
Adding 'EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4' to Archiver.
Uninstalling 'EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

However when I try to install EntityFramework.Core again, it succeeds now.

I want to use EF6, but cannot find it on NuGet, and when I try to install it with the Microsoft Download Center, it never downloads.

I'm a bit lost here so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade NuGet to the latest version from here:
https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/612846

Update:

NuGet at codeplex has been moved to https://github.com/nuget/home

Simply download latest version from:
https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to use IE to download things from Microsoft Download center.  I was able to install EF tools for VS2012 and VS2013.

Next to install EF6 I went to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.  In the console I entered `Install-Package EntityFramework`  You can also do `Install-Package EntityFramework -pre` to get the latest release (7.0.0-beta4)

This worked for me.  Unless someone else has a better solution I will accept this one in a day or so.